# Regex - greedy till next match

Tags: regex

i'm trying to create regex for this pattern:

```
-someKeyword=somePhrase
-someOtherKeyword=someOtherPhrase
```

e.t.c.
the problems is: keyword and phrase should be groups in one match, also phrase can contain character '-' as well, for now i have this: `-(?<keyword>[^=]*)=(?<phrase>[^-]*)`
but this doesn't support '-' character in phrase and i can't solve this problem, any suggestions?

Comment: `-(?<keyword>\w+)=(?<phrase>.*?)(?=-\w+=|$)`? If "keywords" only contain letters/digits/_, this will work. Replace `\w` with any "keyword" matching pattern, just I think `[^=]` is too generic.

Comment: yup, that worked, just modified a little: `-(?<keyword>[\w. ]+)=(?<phrase>.*?)(?=-[\w. ]+=|$)` guess should read about what this last parentheses does, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the keys can contain any letters, digits, underscores, dot and whitespace characters you may use

```
-(?<keyword>[\w\s.]+)=(?<phrase>.*?)(?=-[\w\s.]+=|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AevknZ/1/).

**Details**

- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?<keyword>[\w\s.]+)`  - a "keyword" group: 1+ letter, digit, underscore, dot, 
  whitespace chars
- `=` - an equals sign
- `(?<phrase>.*?)` - a "phrase" group: any 0 or more characters other than line break chars, as **few** (due to `*?`) as possible, up to the leftmost...
- `(?=-[\w\s.]+=|$)` - (a positive lookahead matching a) location that is immediately followed with `-`, 1+ letters/digits/underscores/dots/whitespaces and then `=` or end of string.

Answer (score -2):

`-(?<keyword>[\w. ]+)=(?<phrase>.*?)(?=-[\w. ]+=|$)`

Comment: Instead of posting an answer without any clarification, consider accepting the posted answer which explain the pattern and could make any updates according to your requirements.

Comment: just accepted it, i just posted the one given first in comments (and that is why i posted it, because i can't accept comment as answer)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it